# How do I remove squared brackets from data that is saved as a list in a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, regex

The data is like this and it is in a data frame.

```
    PatientId   Payor
0   PAT10000    [Cash, Britam]
1   PAT10001    [Madison, Cash]
2   PAT10002    [Cash]
3   PAT10003    [Cash, Madison, Resolution]
4   PAT10004    [CIC Corporate, Cash]
```

I want to remove the square brackets and filter all patients who used at least a certain mode of payment eg madison then obtain their ID. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried some code already?

Comment: Yes. I have tried using regex then loop through the column and it is not working.

Comment: If this is all just one string, then `PAT\d{5}(?=\s*[^\n]*Madison)` should work I think (Change Madison for whatever payment method)

Comment: @KeldanChapman The code is not working. There is a "Type error: string indices must be integers"

Comment: @BoredGeek Then it must be one string then. I thought perhaps it was a dict. Did you try the regex I posted?

Comment: @KeldanChapman It is not one string but its entries in a dataframe.

Comment: @KeldanChapman let me try it

Comment: @BoredGeek a pandas dataframe? Sorry I haven't used pandas. But I am looking at the documentation now. Maybe try something like 
```python
ids = []
for i, patID in enumerate(dataframe['PatientID']):
    if 'Madison' in dataframe['Payor'][i]:
        ids.append(patID)
```
If that doesn't work then I'll leave this for someone more experienced haha

Comment: You need to post you're code. Then we can help improve it. Best post a minimal, complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: @KeldanChapman still not working. I tried this code that obtained all patients who used Sunshine ltd. ```matching = [i for i in dataframe if "Sunshine Ltd." in i]
matching``` and it worked. The problem is i'm unable to identify the pat ID since it doesn't return the IDs column

Comment: @KeldanChapman Your previous code works, thanks. It generates the IDs only. Can i get a way to generate both the IDs and the corresponding payor column?

Comment: @BoredGeek Sure, i just installed pandas, I'll post an answer in just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a list of tuples (id, payor). (`df` is the dataframe)

```py
payment = 'Madison'
ids = [(id, df.Payor[i][1:-1]) for i, id in enumerate(df.PatientId) if payment in df.Payor[i]]
```

Comment: Actually, this assumes that the Payor column is just strings that look like lists. If it is actually lists, then don't use the `[1:-1]`, you can use `', '.join(df.Payor[i])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

let's say, your data frame variable initialized as "df" and after removing square brackets, you want to filter all elements containing "Madison" under "Payor" column

```
df.replace({'[':''}, regex = True)
df.replace({']':''}, regex = True)

filteredDf = df.loc[df['Payor'].str.contains("Madison")]
print(filteredDf)
```